# AD user stops working then throws Access Denied page

Tags: 2013, active-directory, user-accounts

I have a problem with one AD user on my test environment. It suddenly stopped working, even logging with it on remote desktop resulted in incorrect password (which wasn't changed, and the user has Password never expires option enabled). I've deleted the user from AD and added it again. Then deleted the user in sharepoint Users management and added again. Now when accessing the site (whatever page) the user is redirected to Access denied page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it just for one specific user? What errors you get in the ULS log?

Comment: it's just 1 user, but from the logs it seems that userprofile import is messed up. there is a recurrent error:

UpdatedConcurrencyException: The object UserProfileImportJob Name=User Profile Service Application_ProfileImportJob was updated by another user.  Determine if these changes will conflict, resolve any differences, and reapply the second change.  This error may also indicate a programming error caused by obtaining two copies of the same object in a single thread.